# Unzip a zip file in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, zip, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to develop code to unzip file from the zip file in Silverlight 5. The files are in a directory within the zip file.

I translated this code I found elsewhere from c# to VB since we are a VB shop. It is failing on the fourth line "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".
I realize now that the problem is that the third line is expecting a relative uri and I am passing it a file, but I don't know how to fix this.

Can you tell me what is wrong with this code. I will also welcome other ideas.

Thanks.

```
Public Shared Function GetZipContents(ByVal filename As String) As String()

        Try



            Dim zipStream As System.IO.Stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
            Dim zipInfo As New StreamResourceInfo(zipStream, Nothing)
            Dim streamInfo As StreamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(zipInfo, New Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative))
            Dim fileStream As Stream = streamInfo.Stream

        Dim names As New List(Of String)()
        Dim reader As New BinaryReader(fileStream)
        Do While reader.ReadUInt32() = &H4034B50

            ' Skip the portions of the header we don't care about
            reader.BaseStream.Seek(14, SeekOrigin.Current)
            Dim compressedSize As UInteger = reader.ReadUInt32()
            Dim uncompressedSize As UInteger = reader.ReadUInt32()
            Dim nameLength As Integer = reader.ReadUInt16()
            Dim extraLength As Integer = reader.ReadUInt16()
            Dim nameBytes() As Byte = reader.ReadBytes(nameLength)
            names.Add(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(nameBytes, 0, nameLength))
            reader.BaseStream.Seek(extraLength + compressedSize, SeekOrigin.Current)

        Loop
        ' Move the stream back to the begining
        fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Return names.ToArray()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I would have time to explore the suggestions. I did find a way to accomplish my goal on my own. See the code below. I would be using this code either because the Technical Leader here prefers I do it a different way using a WCF service. Warning I was not able to test this code 100% since I am not planning to use it, but it is close to being right.

Imports ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip

```
Public Shared Sub UnZip(ByVal SrcFile As String, ByVal DstFile As String, ByVal BufferSize As Integer)

    Try
        Dim _FileName As String
        Dim _ZipEntry As ZipEntry
        Dim _FileStreamOut As FileStream = Nothing
        Dim _Done As Boolean = False


        Dim _FileStreamIn As New FileStream(SrcFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim _ZipInStream As New ZipInputStream(_FileStreamIn)


        Do Until _Done = True
            _ZipEntry = _ZipInStream.GetNextEntry()
            If IsNothing(_ZipEntry) Then
                _Done = True
                Exit Do
            End If
            _FileName = DstFile & "\" & _ZipEntry.Name
            _FileName = _FileName.Replace("/", "\")

            If Right(_FileName, 1) = "\" Then
                If Directory.Exists(_FileName) = False Then
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(_FileName)
                End If
            Else
                _FileStreamOut = New FileStream(_FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

                Dim size As Integer
                Dim buffer(BufferSize - 1) As Byte
                Do
                    size = _ZipInStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    _FileStreamOut.Write(buffer, 0, size)
                Loop While size > 0
            End If
        Loop

        _ZipInStream.Close()
        _FileStreamOut.Close()
        _FileStreamIn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quick and dirty way to unzip in Silverlight.
Use Application.GetResourceStream Method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190632(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out my blogpost on this: http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2010/08/25/REALLY-small-unzip-utility-for-Silverlight-e28093-Part-2.aspx