# Dynazip Not Working

Tags: vb.net, zip

I am using Dynazip to unzip a file. The problem is it's not working. I added the first three lines to make sure that the zip exists, It passes that but then always returns a -1 indicating that no files were found.

```
If File.Exists(l_ZipFile) = False Then
            Return -1
        End If

        Dim l_intCounter As Integer
        With m_objUnzip
            .ZIPFile = l_ZipFile
            .Filespec = sFile2Get
            .RecurseFlag = True
            .Destination = Path.GetTempPath
            .QuietFlag = True
            .ActionDZ = CDUnZipNET.DUZACTION.UNZIP_COUNTALLZIPMEMBERS
            For l_intCounter = 0 To .ReturnCount - 1
                .UnZIPIndex = l_intCounter
                .ActionDZ = DUZACTION.UNZIP_GETINDEXEDZIPINFO
                If UCase(sFile2Get) = UCase(Right(.zi_FileName, Len(sFile2Get))) Then
                    Return .zi_Index
                End If
            Next

            Return -1
        End With
```

I have been asked to get Dynazip to work. I have already solved the problem using another third party product. Also is there any documentation for Dynazip. I cannot find it. This code was a cut and paste from another program.

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the company that wrote Dynazip is out of business, however it is possible to purchase the source code, if you want to go that route.

I found out that we has a license to C1Zip from Component One so we decided to use that product.

If you are looking for a free product, iconic zip was a product that I got to work. Follow this thread for more details.

[Unzip a zip file in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639458/unzip-a-zip-file-in-silverlight)